# Kubernetes/Istio - Restart a service on error

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, istio, application-restart, servicemesh

I have an application deployed in Kubernetes.  I am using the Istio service mesh.  One of my services needs to be restarted when a particular error occurs.  Is this something that can be achieved using Istio?

I don't want to use a cronjob.  Also, making the application restart itself seems like an anti-pattern.

The application is a node js app with fastify.

Comment: If the application is able to detect that it's in an unrecoverable state, it's acceptable to really loudly logging an error message and exiting (from within the application code itself), especially if you know something externally will restart you.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, question is how can I make that external restart possible with Istio.

Comment: Istio is totally unrelated to this.  Another approach could be to use a Kubernetes [liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) if the cluster can detect the pod is unreachable; but if you're going to add a liveness hook to your code, [the Kubernetes documentation also endorses just crashing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#when-should-you-use-a-liveness-probe) on unrecoverable failure.

Answer (score 1):

Istio is a network connection tool. I was creating this answer when [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) made a very correct mention in a comment:

> Istio is totally unrelated to this. Another approach could be to use a Kubernetes [liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) if the cluster can detect the pod is unreachable; but if you're going to add a liveness hook to your code, [the Kubernetes documentation also endorses just crashing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#when-should-you-use-a-liveness-probe) on unrecoverable failure.

The [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) uses liveness probes to know when to restart a container. For example, liveness probes could catch a deadlock, where an application is running, but unable to make progress. Restarting a container in such a state can help to make the application more available despite bugs.

See also:

- [health checks on the cloud - GCP example](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-setting-up-health-checks-with-readiness-and-liveness-probes)
- [creating custom rediness/liveness probe](https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-kubernetes-operator/issues/1395)
- [customization liveness probe](https://oracle.github.io/weblogic-kubernetes-operator/userguide/managing-domains/domain-lifecycle/liveness-readiness-probe-customization/)